# RobotModel error RVIZ

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, urdf

I am trying to add a scooter URDF to my package so I can add sensors and use it on ROS2 - gazebo. I came across a [github repo](https://github.com/bxtbold/autonomous-scooter/tree/main) that include the scooter URDF in and meshes (everything I need). I tried adding these assests to my package and for testing puposes I made a lunch file that echo's robot desciption topic and some other information (fig.1)
[image: fig.1]

it's working fine since it detected all links

I tried to open RVIZ to visualize the robot model, but it didnt show the scooter(fig.2)
[image: fig.2]

and the rviz terminal showed this error(fig.3)
[image: fig.3]

I would appricate any help I want to know if there is an easier approche to include this scooter model to my project.
Thank you for the help in advance